# Recive json log from Tcp on siddhi

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I got a functional siddhi file in the editor using the event simulator but i'm unable to gather data using the tcp source, is there some kind of pattern that it needs to match to be able to be recived?

I tried it in the last 2 versions of the software and as i read that in this last version of it they will change nearly all the tcp protocol i thought that i should be able to recive some kind of data, i saw de data on the tcpdump but not at the event

```
@source(type = 'tcp', 
    @map(type = 'json', fail.on.missing.attribute = "false", 
        @attributes(severity = "$.rawdata.panos.Severity", ipsrc = "$.source.ip", ipdst = "$.destination.ip", evento = "$.event.type", tipoAmenaza = "$.threat.type", eventCategory = "$.event.action", name = "$.organization.name", network = "$.rawdata.panos.SourceLocation")))
define stream LogStream (name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string, network string);
```

it should recive the event and save it in memory for being processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the URL you are using to publish the events?
By default, the endpoint will be exposed at **tcp://0.0.0.0:9892**. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-io-tcp/api/3.0.0/#source) for more details on configuring the tcp source.

Furthermore, if you observe any stacktrace in the console, please share it as well so that we can use it to guide you through to debug the issue.

Comment: i use the default url, but i dont get any feedback in the console

Comment: Can you please share your complete Siddhi App.
Also, from the client side which you use to push the tcp events, do you see any connection issues.

Comment: i want to use de tcp to recieve data sent by logstash, so i don't have the push side of the events

Comment: Can you try with the following app. Added a log sink.
@source(type = 'tcp', 
    @map(type = 'json', fail.on.missing.attribute = "false", 
        @attributes(severity = "$.rawdata.panos.Severity", ipsrc = "$.source.ip", ipdst = "$.destination.ip", evento = "$.event.type", tipoAmenaza = "$.threat.type", eventCategory = "$.event.action", name = "$.organization.name", network = "$.rawdata.panos.SourceLocation")))
@sink(type='log')
define stream LogStream (name string, ipsrc string, ipdst string, evento string, tipoAmenaza string, eventCategory string, severity string, network string);

Comment: still not seeing nothing, [2019-06-11 10:27:42,748]  WARN {io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap} - Unknown channel option 'TCP_NODELAY' for channel '[id: 0x72691a88]'
[2019-06-11 10:27:42,751]  INFO {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.tcp.transport.TCPNettyServer} - Tcp Server started in 0.0.0.0:9892
[2019-06-11 10:27:42,751]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorService} - Siddhi App Alerting deployed successfully

Comment: Can you try sending an appropriate JSON object that matches your stream definition manually? It seems Stream Processor is not receiving events. Here is a sample tcp client for reference[1]. Also refer the tcp samples within Stream Processor[2].

[1]https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/blob/master/modules/samples/sample-clients/tcp-client/src/main/java/org/wso2/sp/tcp/client/TCPClient.java
[2]https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/tree/master/modules/samples/artifacts/ReceiveTCPinJSONFormat

Comment: i made it to wark using the client but that seems to be a problem if i need to run a second instance on a system with high load

Comment: I didn't understand your last concern. Please elaborate more.
Furthermore, if you were able to publish through the client, we can rule out any Stream Processor side issues. That means Stream Processor accepts traffic as expected. 
You might have to debug the logstash publishing configurations.